# Set the imagebutoon for different size of device does not working

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I add the picture for `48*48` , `72*72` and `96*96` to `mdpi` , `ldpi` and `hdpi` respective.

And add the following code in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<supports-screens 
             android:largeScreens="true"   
             android:normalScreens="true"  
             android:smallScreens="true"   
             android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

**First Question:**

The app will capture the suitable picture by itself when I do the above operation ?

**Second Question:**

But how to setup the Button in the `xml` file ?

If app will capture the suitable picture by itself , so I have set the `width` and the `height` to `match_parent` like the following code?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ImageBtulayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/BackButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/back"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/recordButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/no_delete" />

         <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/download_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/download"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I modify the code like the above.

And I install the APP to the device which the size is 4.7 inch.

But the icon seem too small.

It like the following picture

[image]

How to remove the part of gray on imageButton ?
**Does there has any wrong ??**

Comment: have you solved or not?this is problem of your image..please post your image here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing two different concepts. One is a screen's pixel density or DPI and another is a screen's size. In general, phones are considered normal size and tablets are considered large size.

I recommend you read through this entire article which highlights a lot of valuable points regarding supporting different screen sizes and screen densities:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In general though, Android allows the user to define different resources for different device configurations (including screen size and screen density, among others). This is done through the use of (resource/configuration) qualifiers. These are defined by a hiphen, and then the qualifier name on certain folders inside your /res/ directory.

For example, if you wanted to define different images for different screen densities, you would create a new drawable directory for each supported screen density and put the appropriate resources in each.

- /res/drawable-mdpi/
- /res/drawable-ldpi/
- /res/drawable-hdpi/

Then, when Android goes to look for a resource, it will first look for a directory which matches the device's screen density qualifier and get's the resource from there. The resources will share the same name, but will be in different folders, which allows you to define the different resources but also allows Android to resolve them into their different configurations.

So let's look at your questions:
**The app will capture the suitable picture by itself when I do the above operation?**
As described above, as long as you have arranged yor resources with the appropriate qualifiers, then yes, Android will be able to resolve them correctly. However, note that this has nothing to do with the  tag in your manifest.

**But how to setup the Button in the xml file ?**
Your current XML setup is correct.

**If app will capture the suitable picture by itself , so I have set the width and the height to match_parent like the following code?**
Setting your width and height to match_parent will make the views width and height the same as the parent layout, which is incorrect. You want the width and height to wrap the internal content of the view, therefore wrap_content is correct.

Edit: Regarding your question about removing the border, if you want to use ImageButtons, then the documentation (first paragraph) suggests setting the android:background attribute to transparent.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

You might also want to try setting the padding to

```
android:padding="0dp"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: @ThelT I have add the picture in the drawable directory for each supported screen density. But it show the picture like the picture.

Comment: When you say grey, do you mean the gray around the picture, the dark grey around all the images, the lighter grey around the darker grey, or the area with the backdrop? My first suggestion would be to remove the android:background="#000000" tag.

Comment: @MartinWun I've updated my answer with some suggestions. Let us know if this has answered your question and please remember to accept an answer if it has solved your question. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for the first question:**

Android system will choose the image in drawable folder according to device screen density.

**Answer for the second question:**

If the previous code, you set the height and width of the ImageButton to be wrap_content, so the width and height of the ImageButton will be as the size of the captured image from drawable folder, so if you run on device hdpi then the image size (72*72) and the ImageButton dimensions will be also (72*72) px.

Comment: How to remove the part of gray on imageButton ?

Comment: Try to use imageView instate of ImageButton, and put src attribute is the image you want to use (not background attribute), and set scaleType to be FITXY.

Comment: As much as I agree and usually use an ImageView with android:clickable=true, he may want to use an ImageButton for a particular reason. Also, setting the scaleType shouldn't be necessary for an ImageView with width and height as wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

In image button Set Android:src="@drawable/your image"
and set android:background="@null"
it will definatily work for you